# Remotely Executing and Controlling Batch File

Tags: batch-file, powershell-2.0

I am working on a script to remotely execute and provide input to a batch file for the purpose of changing the OU of computers in ActiveDirectory via PowerShell. 
The script I have so far:

```
$domain = "[DOMAIN]"
$User = Get-Credential
Start-Process "NETWORK_FILEPATH\powershell.bat"
Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts *
Restart-Service WinRM
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName [IP] -Credential $User
C:\AUTO_SETUP.bat
"\\hd\it\Unattend-Domain\OU-Script\scriptdisallow.ps1"
```

I have compiled the remote execution portion of this from various articles on StackOverflow, but I still get an error every time I run:

```
C:\AUTO_SETUP.bat is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program
```

Any ideas on how to fix what I have, or a better way to do it? I need to be able to capture the output of the cmd file and pass it input all through the PowerShell window as I will be running from another computer on the domain. The reason for doing it remotely is we only have one machine with the activedirectory module in the domain. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try `cmd /c "C:\auto_setup.bat"`?  If you want to capture its output for further processing, then just `$proc = cmd /c "C:\auto_setup.bat"`.

Comment: @rojo Sorry for such a late response, I tried that command but I was unable to give input to the file once it ran. The bat file requires input from me while it's running, such as my password, the idea being to change the OU of multiple computers using a txt file.

Comment: If you're using `set /P` within your .bat script to prompt for your password and other things, you could put your responses into a txt file in the appropriate order, then redirect the txt file into your batch script to supply the values for the prompts.  `cmd /c "C:\auto_setup.bat" \<responses.txt`.  The `\<` will pass the redirection onto the `cmd /c` thread and prevent it from being erroneously evaluated by PowerShell.  If you're trying to automate the creation of the `PSCredential` object without keyboard input, there are ways to do that as well.